# не отображаются объекты Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics

Не могу понять, почему в результате выполнения кода не отображается овал, причём при использовании метода `paint(Graphics g)` овал отображается.

Класс Painting:

```
public class Painting extends JFrame {
    Pan p = new Pan();

    public  Painting(String s){
        super(s);
        add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Painting p = new Painting("First");
        p.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.setBounds(50, 50, 600, 600);
        p.setVisible(true);
    } 
}
```

Класс Pan:

```
 public class Pan extends JPanel{
     @Override
     public void paintComponents(Graphics g){
         super.paintComponents(g);
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
         g2.setPaint(BLACK);
         g2.fillOval(100, 100, 200, 200);
     }   
 }
```

Comment: Надо панель добавить на фрейм

Comment: У меня она добавлена ( add(p))

Comment: надо что-то вроде setContentPane(p) или getContentPane().add(p)

Comment: попробовал оба метода - результат тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Измени название метода вместо paintComponents - paintComponent (единственное число без 's')